# mapping from one set to another

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I have one set of continuous integer values and corresponding set of non-continuous values, for example:

```
0 -> 22
1 -> 712
2 -> 53
3 -> 12323
...
```

and so on.

Amount of items is very huge (about of 10^9...10^10), so using just plain array is not an option.

Is there data structure that capable of fast mapping from first values to another with moderate memory requirements? For example:

```
ret = map(0); // returns 22
ret = map(3); // returns 12323
```

**Edit**: values in this set are really generated using pseudo-random number generator, so it is not possible to suggest some specific distribution. Question is - is it possible to  lower memory requirements (may be in price of lookup speed)? I mean using something like "perfect hashing" - time required for generate such "perfect hash" doesn't matter.

Comment: In your example your relationship is 1;1, is that the reality or a feature only of this example /

Comment: @High Performance Mark Yes, each index have only one value associated, so using array is not possible only because of memory requirements.

Comment: You state moderate memory requirements, but 10^10 int -> int will run up 100s of GB without compression. Can you tell us else about the dataset?

Comment: You could store the array in a file, which would slow down things. Frankly I do not see any method (apart from compression) to fit the same data into memory.

Comment: If the second set of values it totally random, how can you use less memory then just plain array?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark. If the asker is using 32 bit ints then it's impossible to be 1:1 as 10^10 > 2^32

Comment: @nshy well, that's the question I asking about :)

Comment: The minimum space required to store 10^9 ints uncompressed is achieved by storing them as one huge contiguous array. And this takes up about 4 (or 8) GB of RAM. The most memory efficient method to store them will be to just compute them for each index look up. And if the numbers are pseudo-random then there might not be any other way to store them.

Comment: What is the range of the values?

Comment: @thkala [0; ~10^9] uint32_t will be OK.

Comment: What are the constraints on the pseudo random numbers?  Do those numbers have a meaning in the context of your app?

Comment: @EvilTeach I need random distribution of this values, so it should have uniform distribution and vary from one execution to another.

Answer (score 2):

As your range is continuous, the obvious solution is to store your values in a contiguous int[]. Then value i is `arr[i]`. As the values generated by PRNG, it will be difficult to apply further compression.

Another solution, which trades time for space, is to store the seed of your RNG and recalculate on the fly. This approach could be improved in time, and worsened in space, by storing intermediate seeds. I.e. seed for key 1000, 2000 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to save some space by using *exactly* the number of bits required by each value. For example if your values are only 24 bits, you can save a byte over 32-bit integers. That said, there is only so much memory you can save.

Ob 64-bit machines it would be feasible to `mmap()` a file to a memory address, thus getting over the physical memory limit by using disk storage, at the price of performance.

But since you mentioned using a pseudo-random generator to generate the values, how about just storing the RNG seed for specific indexes and calculating the rest of the values as needed? For example you could store the seed for indexes 0, 100, 200, ... and calculate e.g. 102 by re-seeding the RNG for 100 and calling the generator function three times.

Such an approach would reduce the memory needed by a large factor (100 in this case) and you could lessen the performance cost by bunching or caching your queries.

Answer (score 0):

If the range of your function is the set of numbers generated by a pseudo-random number generator in sequence then you can compress the series down to, well, to the code which generates the sequence plus the state of the PRNG before starting.  For example, the (infinite) series of digits comprising the decimal expansion of pi is easily (and, technically, infinitely) compressed to the code to generate that series; your series could be seen as an example of something almost identical.

So, if you are willing to wait for a long time to get the last elements in the series, you can get very good compression, by writing your series not into a data structure but out of a function.  That is at one end of your time/space trade-off spectrum.

At the other end of the spectrum is an array of all the numbers; this uses lots of space but gives very quick (`O(1)`) access to any desired element in the set.  This doesn't seem to appeal to you for a variety of reasons, but I'm not sure that a cleverer data structure than an array will offer much space saving, or, for that matter, time saving.

The one obvious solution I see is to save a set of intermediate states of the PRNG at intervals, so your 'data' structure would become:

```
ret(0) = prng(seed, other_parameters, ...)
ret(10^5-1)  = prng(seed', other_parameters, ...)
ret(2*(10^5)-1) = prng(seed'', other_parameters, ...)
```

etc.  then, to get element 9765, say, you read (the state of the PRNG at) `ret(0)` and generate the 9765-th pseudo-random number thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the intent is to trade speed for less memory usage.

Imagine that you have some sort of loop that fills the array.

```
int array[intendedArraySize];

seed = 3;
for (size_t z = 0; z < intendedArraySize; z++)
{
     array[z] = some_int_psn_generator(seed);
}
```

After which you can display the values.

```
for (size_t z = 0; z < intendedArraySize; z++)
{
    std::cout << z << " " << array[z] << std::endl;
}
```

If that is indeed the case, consider discarding the array altogether, by simply recalculating the value each time.

```
for (size_t z = 0; z < intendedArraySize; z++)
{
    std::cout << z << " " << some_int_psn_generator(z) << std::endl;
}
```